# Localize a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, internationalization, uitextview

How do I localize a UITextView?
I saw a lot of examples for a UITextField but none for UITextView.

I need to localize my application's description in the about section.

Comment: Yes, in the meanwhile i did it, but to explain me better, is there the possibility to localize different pure text files ? I mean like this: texview.gb and textview.ita and textview.fra etc...   This because textview can be very long and is difficult to indent the words.

Comment: I would just stick with a `.string` file.

Comment: This is what i did, i suppose there's no other solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you've written the description directly into a UITextView in the XIB, you will need to duplicate the XIB (just use Xcode's localization tool) and then copy and paste the translated text into the new XIB.

If there are several XIBs or you need to send the text to translators, just use GENSTRINGS on all the XIBs. See here: http://kb.applingua.com/2011/07/extracting-strings-from-your-m-class-files/