# Xcode/iOS not localizing a specific object consistently

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, localizable.strings, ios8.4

I've localized my app, all the strings resources, storyboard etc. and everything works perfect. I've got hundreds of lines of localization and they all work well, except one specific text view. I have no idea why, but a single specific text view on my app doesn't translate. Everything surrounding, all the siblings are translated correctly but one specific text box doesn't. It stays English whatever I do. I'm sure that the translation (`.strings`) file is correct. I've checked the storyboard ID and its translation in the file and it just seems perfectly valid.

Here is the entry in storyboard translation file:

```
/* Class = "UITextView"; text = "Type here what your club is about. Be clear on what you want in your club."; ObjectID = "G0H-NN-02k"; */
"G0H-NN-02k.text" = "Kulübünün neyle ilgili olduğunu ve kulüpte neleri istediğini buraya yaz.";
```

It's just like all the other entries in the file. The storyboard ID in the translation file is the same ID in the storyboard. I've cleaned build folder, removed everything inside DerivedData, deleted my app from the device, and tried again, but no avail. It's still English.

Why can this happen?

Comment: If your string is last in file, try to move its to inside. Or press Enter after ';'

Comment: Is this a recently-added string?

Comment: @stosha no it's right in between hundreds of other entries. all the others both above and below are working.

Comment: @Clafou nope, it was added just with the others, it's in the middle of the strings file

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I've a lot of entries but the entries

> *Class = "UITextView";*

doesn't work.

Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b)

I may find the solution here: [Localize a UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951865/localize-a-uitextview/13139458#13139458)

It's simple, we can't. Maybe because of the possible text lenght of an UITextView.

Comment: Oh, with storyboards, it's not possible. (at least practically)